# Access-2007 DB in different folder - connection string?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a small project with Access-2007 Database available in directory C:\SVHML_ERP\Data\SVHML_Management.accdb

Therefore my connection string is

```
SVHMLConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source='C:\\SVHML_ERP\\Data\\SVHML_Management.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False;"
```

But, it's simply adding the project directory to it's data source directory ....Iam getting the error like

OleDb Exception was unhandled :
"Could not find file C:\Documents and Settings\Paraman\My Documents\visual studio 2010\projects\My_Applications\My_Applications\SVHML_ERPDataSVHML_Management.accdb

Does anybody can point me the mistake...
Thanks & Regards
Paramu

Comment: You want to add your accdb to your VS Project, am I right?

Comment: Yes.. I wish to add to my project... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the error because of SQL Server Database has been mistyped on Select Query...
Therefore the connection string has not a problem...

After removing the SQl Server Database Name from Query, the path has cleared and works fine...

Thanks for all the helps & Valuable minutes